# How to force the PS Find-Module command to use basic authentication (with PAT) in Windows Domain where the default is NTLM auth?

Tags: powershell, authentication

I can invoke `Find-Module` without the `-Credential` argument and it works just fine. This is  because:

1. the module in question is found on an on-prem NuGet repo in the Windows Domain
2. the default authentication is NTLM

Now I really want to use PAT, which forces me to pass the `-Credential` argument. However, in order to work the authentication must be switched to Basic. And this is where I am stuck.

I know how to configure the NuGet source with the PAT credentials (and `ValidAuthenticationTypes` = `basic`), so I am able to use nuget.exe with PAT. But I specifically need `Find-Module` (and `Install-Module`) to work.

This happens both on Windows Powershell and on PS Core. Here is `Get-Module` output on PS Core:

```
C:\Users\p11f70f> get-module

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-It…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {ConvertFrom-SecureString, ConvertTo-SecureString…
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Ob…
Script     1.4.8.1               PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package,…
Script     1.0.0                 Posh-Git                            {Add-PoshGitToProfile, Expand-GitCommand, Format-…
Script     2.2.5                 PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Fin…
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, …

C:\Users\p11f70f>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ILSpy I traced the execution of the `Find-Module` and my conclusion is that it is impossible to make it work with PAT if the server prefers NTLM.

This is quite frastrating, because some PS flows use in-house logic to interact with the NuGet server (like `Find-Module` and `Install-Module`) yet other flows fallback to `dotnet.exe nuget` or `nuget.exe` (like `Publish-Module`)

The latter recognize the PAT credentials saved in the `$env:APPData\NuGet\NuGet.config` file and the most importantly respect the `validAuthenticationTypes` property which forces them to override NTLM with Basic authentication.

The in-house PS logic does nothing of the kind. Moreover, it gets poisoned by the saved PAT credentials, which would be used with NTLM, which is totally wrong.

What a mess.